# How to Retrieve specific uid key when clicking on recyclerView an object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unique-key

I have built an android application using firebase database. I have a recyclerView in which i saw some objects. When i click on one of the options i want to get the unique id so later i can change some values.

If it where a user i could get the id by FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()

I want something like that but i cannot find it.

For example. I have those two Notifications Objects in the database.
[image: Firebase Instance]

Here when i click on one i need to get the key. I have not added the objects on a list so i can use list.get(position).getId(). Is it possible to get it from getAdapterPosition()?

[image: RecyclerView]

Comment: To get the key of a `DataSnapshot`, call `DataSnapshot.getKey()`. If that doesn't help you fix the problem, show the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you add your code part ?